# Microsoft Security Essentials: keep download scans but disable local activity scans

Tags: performance, download, anti-virus, monitoring, ms-security-essentials

In Microsoft Security Essentials, I used to disable "Monitor file and program activity on your computer" but enable "Scan all downloads." Now, [Microsoft Security Essentials (MSSE) 4.0 removed the ability to configure sub-options of real-time monitoring.](http://contour07.wordpress.com/2012/05/01/changes-in-microsoft-security-essentials-v4-0/) (See [complaints about the beta on Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/mse-protect_start/power-users-will-be-disappointed-with-new-beta/fa1aabd7-08eb-4a65-acd3-8c3e52569de0).) Is there a way to eliminate the local file and program activity? I've looked on Google, in Local Group Policy, and the Registry, yet didn't find anything.

I use Firefox 13.0.1. One option is to start using the [Download Statusbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/download-statusbar/) add-on again, which in the past allowed me to manually specify a virus scanning program, but I'd rather set this up strictly in MSE if I can.

Comment: That is dumb, the file you downloaded could be an virus that has been encrypted and it decrypts during run time, you must scan all the file and program activities also.

Comment: @HackToHell: actually it's not at all dumb, but yes it will be less secure. Still keep in mind that no AV will protect you from APTs.

Comment: Just turn real-time protection off and leave scan downloads turned-on.

Comment: @martineau: My question exactly is how do I do that? Microsoft removed the obvious option to do so.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said turn real-time protection off in MSE and make sure `browser.download.manager.scanWhenDone` is set to true in Firefox's `about:config` settings. See http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.download.manager.scanWhenDone

Comment: @martineau: Just tried that and testing with the [EICAR test virus](http://www.rexswain.com/eicar.html). `browser.download.manager.scanWhenDone` doesn't seem to do anything when "Turn on real-time protection" is disabled.

Comment: You're right, it's broken. Please excuse my uninformed comments...sorry.

Comment: Why are you wanting to disable real-time protection?  Is there a particular application that gets slowed down by AV scans when it's running?  Perhaps you should instead consider just excluding that application's files?